# Finalizing objects after parsing

Tags: java, parsing

Suppose I have, for example, an array of objects generated by parsing a document. These objects look like this:

```
Object{
  id
  text
  anotherProperties
}
```

The first two attributes (id and text) are set during parsing, but now I want to add another Properties(additional attributes), which can't be set during parsing, because it is too complicated to determine them, but depends on text.
How can I achieve this in an elegant way?
In Java?
Thanks for responses

Comment: After you have parsed the document, iterate through a collection of the objects and set the values?

Comment: are you coming from PHP? it's impossible to create a field dynamically in Java without using bytecode manipulation.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ok, I'm in a loop. How could I stop the loop to see the text of object? 2) How could I then assign a property(means to call a setProperty() method) ?

Comment: @MartinM Why do you want to prevent the loop seeing the text? You can assign the property by setting it in the normal way.  The usually problem is not knowing what to set it to.

Comment: @PeterLawrey sorry my english, I want to pause the loop so I can see the text and then set the property

Comment: @MartinM So what is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't know how. I'm on a command line, I force my class to stop at every object and display its text and now??? Only think I can imagine is System.in... I think I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @MartinM Only you know why you are adding properties, what those properties are for and what they should be set to. If you don't know what they are for, I suggest you delete them or ignore them until you do. ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17139/discussion-between-martinm-and-peter-lawrey)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use a HashMap with key of Integer (your id) and a value of DocProperites which consists of text and anotherProperites.

Then when you are ready to set anotherProperties you can retrieve the object from the HashMap and then set it.

For example

```
Map<Integer, DocProperties> map = new HashMap();
```

and DocProperties is

```
public class DocProperties {
    private String text;
    private String anotherProperties;
    //plus the usual setters, getters and ctor
}
```

then when you want to set the anotherProperties you can call

```
map.get(key).setAnotherProperties(....);
```

If you wanted something more dynamic then you could use another HashMap instead of DocProperties. The HashMap could then have keys added and removed as you parse. I wouldnt advise this though as the code could become very messy and bug ridden.